# Is this the right approach to run long running async tasks?

Tags: python, events, asynchronous, celery

I am trying to come up with a notification service for a list of events for which the data is available in the database every few minutes and gets updated using some mechanism. 2 minutes before the next event, I need to read this database and send out the data to my subscribers as a reminder that the event is about to start. This times are not fixed. They depend on the event time of the next event.

Right now I am creating a celery worker for every user who subscribes. I make the specific celery worker go to sleep till the next event, at which point it resumes and sends out the messge.

Something like this:

```
    nextEventDelay = events.getTimeToNextEventInSeconds()

    sleep(nextEventDelay)

    SendEventNotification()
```

But I know, it is not good. For a single person/ 2 people it's working. But for 1000 users, if it spawns 1000 workers, it will not be good.

So my solution? I am thinking of creating a single worker process which will monitor the database for subscribers and once the notification is to be sent out will read from database and send to them. **But, this takes care of only one event. Should I keep this in an infinite for loop to notify about the next event?**

I am using Celery for async task management with redis. The appplication is Python flask application.  Let me know if you need any more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using celery beats you could run a job every x seconds to check if any events are within two minutes of starting. You could then trigger your 'reminder' jobs from that task.

Here is the documentation for periodic celery tasks.
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

I would suggest you stay far away from long running celery tasks as I have not had a great experience with them.

Here is some untested pseudo code to get you started.

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

app = Celery()

@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    # check for events every 20 seconds

    sender.add_periodic_task(20.0, trigger_reminders.s(), name='check for upcoming events')

@app.task
def trigger_reminders(*args, **kwargs):
    upcoming_events = get_upcoming_events()
    for event in upcoming_events:
        send_notification.delay(event)

@app.task
def send_event(*args, **kwargs):
    #Send the user notification
```